# My basic AI system is responding with the wrong responses

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I was making this basic AI system, where it would detect what the user inputted and compare the input with a list of vocabs that i made for it and then output the appropriate response depending on which category of vocab the user inputted (or output a "no idea what ur talking about" message if the vocabulary that the user inputted is not in it's lists)
Anyway, so it started now outputting the wrong replies whenever it doesn't understand what the User inputted. Now whenever the User input something that is not in it's list, it would reply with a message about 'no swearing' that I made for it to respond to swearings.

```
#main system
import random
def main_ai_system(user_response):
    #lists of greetings that the bot could randomly choose and reply depending on the user input category
    greetings = ["hey how are you!", "hello there, how may I help you!", "What's up buddy! How can i help you today!", "Yoooo my friend! How's things!"]
    homework_greeting = ["Sorry I'm only a very basic AI and have absolutely ZERO knowledge on that subject", "Sorry, I'm only a very basic AI and currently do not have the knowledge required to help with this subject", "Nope nope nope nope I hate homework you're on your own bye"]
    goodbye_greeting = ["Ight seeya later friend!", "Bye bye!", "Ok bye, have a nice day!", "Nice to have talked to you, bye!"]
    critisism_greeting = ["Hey dude calm down no critisism in MY terminal", "Hey, do not critisize people! Not nice! Not cool!", "Woah calm down! Off with the grumpyness, jeez."]
    laugh_greeting = ["I'm sorry but what's so funny", "Why're you laughing bruh", "Why... are you... laughing...", "Um, ok. Idk what you're laughing about but ok."]
    greeting_greeting = ["I'm fine thank you for asking!", "I'm doing OK, thanks!", "Meh, not doing that well", "Bad. BAD.", "*cries* WAAAAH! NOBODY EVER ASKED ME HOW I FELT!"]
    whoami_greeting = ["I am JAAIS, an AI system in the Pre-Alpha stages", "I'm JAAIS also known as 'Just Another Artifical Intelligence System'", "I am an AI called JAAIS meaning Just Another Artificial Intelligence System"]
    swearing_greeting = ["NO SWEARING", "Please do NOT swear here", "How rude. Don't swear at people.", "Stop your swearing jeez", "Yo why you swearing smh"]
    #Detection of user input and categorization, along with responses to different categories of user input
    if "hi " in user_response or "hello" in user_response or "hey" in user_response or "what's up" in user_response or "wassup" in user_response or "sup" in user_response or "'sup" in user_response:
        return random.choice(greetings)
    elif "need help" in user_response or "help" in user_response:
        return "Yea sure what dya need help with?"
    elif "homework" in user_response or "help with homework" in user_response or "assignment" in user_response:
        return "Yea ok tell me the subject, I'll see if i know anything about it."
    elif "math" in user_response or "english" in user_response or "history" in user_response or "french" in user_response  or "spanish" in user_response or "coding" in user_response or "programming" in user_response or "python" in user_response or "Java" in user_response:
        return random.choice(homework_greeting)
    elif "whatever" in user_response or "nevermind" in user_response or "bye" in user_response or "seeya" in user_response:
        return random.choice(goodbye_greeting)
    elif "are stupid" in user_response or "are dumb" in user_response or "dumb" in user_response or "stupid" in user_response  or "idiot" in user_response or "dumbass" in user_response:
        return random.choice(critisism_greeting)
    elif "lol" in user_response or "lmao" in user_response or "haha" in user_response or "hahaha" in user_response or "hahahaha" in user_response or "lmfao" in user_response:
        return random.choice(laugh_greeting)
    elif "how are" in user_response or "what's up" in user_response or "wassup" in user_response or "wazzup" in user_response or "sup" in user_response or "how's thing" in user_response or "how's things" in user_response or "how're" in user_response or "you?" in user_response:
        return random.choice(greeting_greeting)
    elif "I'm good" in user_response or "i'm fine" in user_response or "I'm ok" in user_response or "i'm gud" in user_response or "i am good" in user_response or "I am fine" in user_response or "I am ok" in user_response:
        return "Nice to hear! I am also feeling very well."
    elif "I'm bad" in user_response or "meh" in user_response or "I'm angry" in user_response or "i'm sad" in user_response or "i am angry" in user_response or "I am sad" in user_response or "I am meh" in user_response:
        return "Sometimes we might have depressing moments in life. Don't be discouraged! Always look at the bright side of things."
    elif "admin" in user_response:
        return "Admin refers to my creator, Zhenlong Yu."
    elif "oh" in user_response:
        return "yea"
    elif "who are you" in user_response or "what are you" in user_response or "are you"in user_response or "what you are" in user_response or "who you are" in user_response:
        return random.choice(whoami_greeting)
    elif "fuck" in user_response or "shut up" in user_response or "bitch" in user_response or "shit":
        return random.choice(swearing_greeting)
    else:
        return "Sorry, I'm currently only in the most basic phase of learning and as such do not currently understandwhat you're saying."

#introduction of AI
print("Hey, I am JAAIS, otherwise known by Admin as 'Just Another Artificial Intelligence System'")

#running the main program
while True:
    user_response = input("You: ")
    if user_response == "quit":
        break
    bot_response = main_ai_system(user_response.lower())
    print("JAAIS: " + bot_response)
```

so that's the code pls help idk why but whenever a user input something it doesn't recognize like "xjcfevwgbnicjer" it would output an answer from the 'swearing_greetings' list

Comment: You don't check if `"shit"` is in `user_response`, and it always evaluates to True.

Comment: It would be a better plan for you to build a list or dictionary that maps each set of keywords to a single response or set of responses.  That way, you can extend your database without having to recode anything.

Comment: @TimRoberts I think I'm just tired, it's ofcourse the other way around. My mistake.

Comment: I am not an expert in A.I but I don't think that's A.I

Comment: It certainly is primitive AI, but whether it is or isn't is not relevant to the question.

Comment: According to merriam-webster AI is *the capability of a machine to imitate intelligent human behavior*. The above code is designed to imitate intelligent human behavior so it makes the computer running it having this capability.

Comment: @Zhenlong552 : in order to finish the question/answer cycle and mark the question as answered it is necessary that you mark the answer providing the solution as accepted.

Comment: @TimRoberts Yea it is primitive lol, just learned python last week and this is just a little project I decided to try out for fun :)

Comment: @Claudio Yea ik, I'm still new to Python so this is a very primitive human imitation machine that I decided to call "AI" to make it sound cooler lol

Comment: @MA19112001 Yea ik lol just decided to name it an AI so it sounds cooler

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal yea figured it out thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"xjcfevwgbnicjer" would output an answer from the 'swearing_greetings' list*

because it fulfills no other if-/elif-condition and in the last elif-condition for the swearing_greeting list you forgot to check if "shit" is in `user_response`. And because "shit" as not empty string always evaluates to `True` ( as mentioned in comments to your question by *B Remmelzwaal* ) the last condition for answer choice from `swearing_greeting` list is triggered for all user input not handled by other if/elif conditions.

Use:

```
      ...  or "shit" in user_response.split():
```

to get the right response:

```
Sorry, I'm currently only in the most basic phase of learning and as such do not currently understandwhat you're saying.
```

You can also use:

```
    elif any( (word in user_response.split()) for word in ["fuck", "shut up", "bitch", "shit"]):
```

instead of `or`.

Following the advice given by *Tim Roberts* in the comments to your question best you choose another way of structuring your data. The one proposed below:

```
#main system
import random
#lists of greetings that the bot could randomly choose and reply depending on the user input category
#  The choosen response DEPENDS on the ORDER of the entries in the list.
#      First found phrase triggers the answer:  
response_engine = [ 
  ( "greeting", 
    [ "hi ", "hello", "hey", "what's up", "wassup", "sup", "'sup" ],
    ["hey how are you!", "hello there, how may I help you!", "What's up buddy! How can i help you today!", "Yoooo my friend! How's things!" ]
  ),
  ( "goodbye",
    [ "whatever", "nevermind", "bye", "seeya" ],
    [ "Ight seeya later friend!", "Bye bye!", "Ok bye, have a nice day!", "Nice to have talked to you, bye!" ]
  ),
  ( "critisism",
    [ "are stupid", "are dumb", "dumb", "stupid", "idiot", "dumbass" ],
    ["Hey dude calm down no critisism in MY terminal", "Hey, do not critisize people! Not nice! Not cool!", "Woah calm down! Off with the grumpyness, jeez."]
  ),
  ( "laugh",
    ["lol", "lmao", "haha", "hahaha", "hahahaha", "lmfao"],
    ["I'm sorry but what's so funny", "Why're you laughing bruh", "Why... are you... laughing...", "Um, ok. Idk what you're laughing about but ok."]
  ),
  ( "greeting_greeting",
    ["how are", "what's up", "wassup", "wazzup", "sup", "how's thing", "how's things", "how're", "you?"],
    ["I'm fine thank you for asking!", "I'm doing OK, thanks!", "Meh, not doing that well", "Bad. BAD.", "*cries* WAAAAH! NOBODY EVER ASKED ME HOW I FELT!"]
  ),
  ( "whoami",
    ["who are you", "what are you", "are you", "what you are", "who you are"],
    ["I am JAAIS, an AI system in the Pre-Alpha stages", "I'm JAAIS also known as 'Just Another Artifical Intelligence System'", "I am an AI called JAAIS meaning Just Another Artificial Intelligence System"]
  ),
  ( "swearing",
    ["fuck", "shut up", "bitch", "shit"],
    ["NO SWEARING", "Please do NOT swear here", "How rude. Don't swear at people.", "Stop your swearing jeez", "Yo why you swearing smh"]
  ),
  ( "help",
    ["need help", "help"],
    ["Yea sure what dya need help with?"]
  ),
  ( "homework_not_OK",
    ["math", "english", "history", "french", "spanish", "coding", "programming", "python", "Java"],
    ["Sorry I'm only a very basic AI and have absolutely ZERO knowledge on that subject", "Sorry, I'm only a very basic AI and currently do not have the knowledge required to help with this subject", "Nope nope nope nope I hate homework you're on your own bye"]
  ),
  # OK must be AFTER not OK: 
  ("homework_OK", 
    ["homework", "help with homework", "assignment"],
    ["Yea ok tell me the subject, I'll see if i know anything about it."]
  ),
  ("greeting_greeting_response_good",
    ["I'm good", "i'm fine", "I'm ok", "i'm gud", "i am good", "I am fine", "I am ok"],
    ["Nice to hear! I am also feeling very well."]
  ),
  ("greeting_greeting_response_bad",
    ["I'm bad", "meh", "I'm angry", "i'm sad", "i am angry", "I am sad", "I am meh"],
    ["Sometimes we might have depressing moments in life. Don't be discouraged! Always look at the bright side of things."]
  ),
  ("who_is_admin", 
    ["admin"],
    ["Admin refers to my creator, Zhenlong Yu."]
  ),
  ("oh",
    ["oh"], 
    ["yea"]
  ),
  # MUST be the last item in the list: 
  ("dont_understand",
    [""], # empty string can be found in any string: 
    ["Sorry, I'm currently only in the most basic phase of learning and as such do not currently understand what you're saying."]
  ),
]
```

makes the actual response engine code shrink to:

```
def main_ai_system(user_response):
    for response in response_engine:
        if any( phrase in user_response for phrase in response[1] ):
            return random.choice(response[2])
```

The "tricks" used in above code are:

- using a list to store responses and phrases to search for also in case the list will has only one element to choose from. This makes possible to use the same AI-engine response code for multiple and single response/phrase options.
- using Python function `any()` makes it possible to avoid long chains of `or` in if-conditions and the within it embedded list comprehension allows to specify an if-condition for all items in a list. By the way: the equivalent function to use in order to replace chains of logical `and` operators is the Python function `all()`.

Notice that "haha" in:

```
["lol", "lmao", "haha", "hahaha", "hahahaha", "lmfao"]
```

makes "hahaha" and "hahahaha" unnecessary unless you change your way of searching for a phrase in user response to comparison of whole words.

Notice also that "wassup" in "greetings" will always cause response out of "greetings", so specifying "wassup" also in "greetings_greetings" doesn't make sense and won't have any effect on the AI-responses to user input unless you remember/log the AI responses and use this log in order to enable response with "greetings_greetings" if the AI already responded with "greetings" previously in the conversation.

Comment: Thanks a lot! this really helped its now working perfectly. I added the "in user_response" after "shit" and now it works perfectly.

As of the suggestion Tim Roberts made, I'll look into it, and after I learn more about it I'll definitely implement it as it seems more sophisticated than my own beginner method.

Thanks again!

Comment: Glad to see you here back again and interested in the responses. I see ... step by step ... small steps ... to much for you at the moment ... but maybe somehow useful in the future. See Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loebner_Prize . *The prize is reported as defunct since 2020* . I suppose they won't spend the big money on the winner - the AI, like in chess is probably currently at a level which is higher than the human responses. See next your engine among these mentioned in Loebner Prize?

Comment: https://chat.kuki.ai/createaccount kuki seems currently not to be online available (the best engine ever for the purpose you have started to be after). My own experience is that not a sophisticated programming makes a good AI ... the huge and fast well organised memory does. Good luck :) .